# Imagem responsiva mobile

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Queria saber como eu faço para deixar a primeira imagem quando for dispositivo mobile a imagem fica so ela na tela so a primeira no caso"a do computador"sem ficar dividido do jeito que ta aparecendo a "sobre"

```
<div class="carousel-inner" id="home">


        <div class="carousel-item ">
            <img src="imgs/lago.jpg" class="img-fluid d-block">
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block text-light">
                <!-- d-none some se minimiza -->
                <div class="img1" align="center" id="nome">Alyson Zancanaro Ramos</div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img src="imgs/pc.jpg" class="img-fluid d-block">
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block text-light">
                <div class="img2" align="center">Alyson Zancanaro Ramos</div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Cara não deu para entender bem o que vc quer... vc quer que quando for mobile o Slider suma e fique só uma imagem estática ali sem ficar girando é isso?

Comment: Eu quero que a imagem  do "computador" atinja toda a tela do celular e nao fiquei dividida com a de baixo

Comment: Acho que entendi, vc quer que o slider ocupe a altura inteira da tela correto? Vc sabe que se vc fizer isso as laterais da sua imagem praticamente vão sumir e vai ficar aparecendo só o pedaço do meio né? Tipo no caso da sua imagem muito provavelmente a xícara vai sumir a esquerda e o cara de azul vai sumir a direita... pode ser assim?

Comment: Queria que ela centraliza-se sem sumi nada ai nao é possível ?

Comment: Cara é possível, mas a imagem vei ficar deformada... Ela vai ficar achatada de mais!! Tipo assim http://www.myinternalgps.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/Stretched-Face-Oct-Post-credit-Bobcatnorth1.jpg é isso que vc quer?

Answer (score 0):

O próprio bootstrap já tem classes prontas para isso, para não exibir um elemento dom em dispositivos diferentes,

**Bootstrap 4**
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/

Boostrap 3

Exemplo

.hidden-xs (Para ocultar div, ou outros elementos em celulares)
.hidden-sm (Para ocultar div, ou outros elementos em dispositivos médios)
.hidden-md ...
e outras classes